# Why does my code throw a ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to simply place an image, `dotpowder.png`, where you touch the screen. Simple enough, right? Apparently not, as the image is to be a class, with attributes so I can treat it as a dynamic object instead of an ImageView. Here is the code for the `DotCanvas.java`:

```
package com.dhg.dots;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;

public class DotCanvas extends View {
    private Context mContext;
    public DotCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        mContext = context;
    }
    private DotBase dot;

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DotHandler.dotList.size(); i++) {
            dot = DotHandler.dotList.get(i);
            dot.setY(dot.getY() + 1);

            canvas.drawBitmap(dot.getBitmap(), dot.getX(), dot.getY(), null);
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Point dotPoint = new Point();
        dotPoint.x = (int)event.getX();
        dotPoint.y = (int)event.getY();
        new DotPowder(mContext, dotPoint.x, dotPoint.y);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is the **updated** `DotBase.java`:

```
package com.dhg.dots;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class DotBase {
    private Context mContext;
    private Bitmap dotBitmap;

    public DotBase(Context context, float x, float y) {
        DotHandler.addDotToArray(this);
        mContext = context;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.dotpowder);
        dotBitmap = bitmap;
        xCoord = x;
        yCoord = y;
    }

    private float xCoord;
    private float yCoord;

    public void setX(float x) {
        xCoord = x;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        yCoord = y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return xCoord;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return yCoord;
    }

    public void setGraphic(int id) {
        dotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return dotBitmap;
    }
}
```

And finally, here is `DotPowder.java`:

```
package com.dhg.dots;

import android.content.Context;

public class DotPowder extends DotBase {
    public DotPowder(Context context, float x, float y) {
        super(context, x, y);

        setGraphic(R.drawable.dotpowder);
    }
}
```

The `ClassNotFoundException` occurs when the new `DotBase` is instantiated, but I have no idea why.

P.S. Here is DotHandler.java, the main Activity:

```
package com.dhg.dots;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DotHandler extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static List<DotBase> dotList = new ArrayList<DotBase>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -946727550332680940L;
    };
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DotCanvas(this));
    }

    public static void addDotToArray(DotBase dot) {
        if (dotList.size() == 0) {
            dotList.add(0, dot);
        }
        else {
            dotList.add(dotList.size() + 1, dot);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dhg.dots.DotBase.<init>(DotBase.java:17)
    at com.dhg.dots.DotPowder.<init>(DotPowder.java:7)
    at com.dhg.dots.DotCanvas.onTouchEvent(DotCanvas.java:32)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3778)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:885)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1716)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1124)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2125)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dhg.dots.DotBase.<init>(DotBase.java:17)
    at com.dhg.dots.DotPowder.<init>(DotPowder.java:7)
    at com.dhg.dots.DotCanvas.onTouchEvent(DotCanvas.java:32)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3778)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1716)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1124)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2125)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dhg.dots.DotBase.<init>(DotBase.java:17)
    at com.dhg.dots.DotPowder.<init>(DotPowder.java:7)
    at com.dhg.dots.DotCanvas.onTouchEvent(DotCanvas.java:32)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3778)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1716)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1124)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2125)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also, as you can tell from the stack trace, it has started throwing NullPointerExceptions as well.

Comment: He wrote about ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: I think hackbod is meaning the stack trace

Comment: Oh, sorry, DotHandler is the main Activity of the app, I'll edit the OP. I'll also add the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is indeed in this line:

```
private Bitmap dotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.dotpowder);
```

This code is called before you call the constructor, and surely mContext is null here. Just place the initialization code inside your constructor and you'll be OK. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, so I changed the beginning of DotBase.java:/nblah

Comment: Please ignore the first comment, that was an accident. Anyway, thanks.
So I changed the beginning of DotBase.jav from:

`public class DotBase {
    private Context mContext;

    public DotBase(Context context, float x, float y) {
        DotHandler.addDotToArray(this);
        mContext = context;
        xCoord = x;
        yCoord = y;
    }

    private Bitmap dotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.dotpowder);
    private float xCoord;
    private float yCoord;`

Comment: I will update the OP with the updated code, which now throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Ignore my other comments here, please. This is my fist time on StackOverflow, and I still don't know how to do some things.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a dumb mistake to cause the IndexOutOfBoundsException, I was using `dotList.add(dotList.size() + 1)`, so the cause of the exception was obvious when I saw that. I fixed that that, and now it works just fine. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The method call "mContext.getResources()" at the line 17 in DotBase.java may raise NullPointerException.
The origin of DotBase#mContext is the parameter "mContext" in the constructor of DotCanvas class.

Please check what object is passed through the DotCanvas constructor.

Comment: As you can see from DotHandler, DotHandler itself is the object passed to the constructor of DotCanvas. I don't know if that is problematic, although I don't believe it is.

Comment: chech `mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.dotpowder` might be null while `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` debug or `s.out` value